# dotnet test reports no tests available in project targeting net47

Tags: .net, testing, asp.net-core, nunit

When I run dotnet test against my test projects, I get the error message

`No test is available in ......dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.`

I'm using this command line:

`dotnet test platform\Decideware.Platform.Tests\Decideware.Platform.Tests.csproj  --configuration Release --framework net47 --no-restore --no-build`

My project targets net47. It uses NUnit 2.6.4 (it is a recently converted legacy project).

I'm importing what I think are all the packages I need:

`<PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="2.6.*" />
<PackageReference Include="NUnitTestAdapter" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.6.*" />`

How can I get my tests to run?

Comment: Does it happen on your local machine or during CI process (on e.g. on VSTS)?

Comment: @DmitryPavlov It happens on both

Comment: What if to create new test project from scratch and target it to NET 4.7 - does it work on your side?